# Handlebars #each top level only

Tags: javascript, handlebars.js

I am just starting out with handlebars so I apologise in advance if this is very simple or has already been answered (I cannot find anything searching).

I have a multi level json object that I want to display in my template. However I only want the top level elements displayed and not displaying if they have child properties.

Current Template:

```
<div id="example">
{{#each myObject}}
   {{@key}}: {{this}}<br>
{{/each}}
</div>
```

Example Object:

```
{
a: value1,
b: value2,
c: value3,
d: { a: 1, b: 2, c: 3 },
e: value5
}
```

My desired (simplified) output is:

```
<div>
a: value1<br>
b: value2<br>
c: value3<br>
e: value5<br>
</div>

<div>
d<br>

a: 1<br>
b: 2<br>
c: 3<br>
</div>
```

What I am struggling with is how to add an if to my template in order to test if the property has a child object beneath it and not display it in the first section.

Then for each property that does have a child object, display it beneath (or elsewhere) and iterate through each of its child properties.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this by creating a helper function:

```
Handlebars.registerHelper('checkForJson', function (a) {
        if(typeof a =='object')
    {
        return true;
   }
   return false;
});
```

And to use this in you html :

```
 <div id="example">
                {{#each .}}
            {{#if (checkForJson this) }}
                    {{#each this}}
                         {{@key}}: {{this}}<br>
                    {{/each}}
            {{else}}
                    {{@key}}: {{this}}<br>
            {{/if}}
        {{/each}}
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, this solves that problem, what I hadn't realised is I have arrays inside some of my objects which causes some odd effects but should be able to clear that up relatively easily with a bit of modification of the above.